# Redirect specific view based on a field django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I need to redirect after login to a specific view according to the `Profesor` field, if this is False, redirect to `vistaAlumno`, if True, redirect to `vistaProfesor`.

views.py

```
def profesor(user):
    return (user.profesor)

@login_required
@user_passes_test(profesor)
def vistaProfesor(request):
    rut= request.user.rut_user
    notas = Nota.objects.select_related('id_asignatura','rut_alumno').filter(rut_profesor=rut)
    observaciones = Observacion.objects.filter(rut_profesor=rut)    
    return render(request, 'core/vistaProfesor.html', {'notas': notas,  'observaciones': observaciones})
        


@login_required
def vistaAlumno(request):
    if request.user.profesor == False:
        rut= request.user.rut_user         
        notas = Nota.objects.select_related('id_asignatura').select_related('rut_profesor').filter(rut_alumno=rut)
        asistencias = Asistencia.objects.filter(rut_alumno=rut)
        #Necesito unir la tabla observacion con profesor, lo cual ya hace, pero luego quiero unir la tabla profesor con asignatura y mostrar el nombre en el vistaAlumno.html
        observaciones = Observacion.objects.select_related('rut_profesor').filter(rut_alumno=rut)          
        curso = Alumno.objects.filter(rut_alumno=rut).values_list('id_curso')
        horarios = Horario.objects.select_related('rut_profesor','id_asignatura','id_sala').filter(id_curso__in=curso)   
        return render(request, 'core/vistaAlumno.html', {'notas': notas, 'asistencias': asistencias, 'observaciones': observaciones, 'horarios': horarios})
    else:
        vistaProfesor(request)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):  
    profesor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rut_user = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/vistaAlumno'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to illustrate Django's authentication framework used to log in to a website. From here I hope you will be able to use this to solve your issue.

Assuming that we have already collected users' usernames and passwords from our `forms.py` file in the app application directory:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

N.B: This form will authenticate users against the database. The `PasswordInput` renders the `password` HTML element.

Edit the `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request, username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
        
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)    
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated') 
                    #or
                    # return render(request, 'some_other_page.html', {'form': form})
                else:
                    return HtppResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

In the apps' `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #post views
    path('login/', views.user_login, 'login'),
]
```

We should update the `urls.py` file in the main project directory assumming our project's called `testproject`.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
]
```

The `app` app directory:

```
templates/
    account/
        login.html
    base.html
```

Edit the `base.html` template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Put title here{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Test Project</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the `account/login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log in"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```